# Calculate Impact of Input Tokens on BERT (or other classifier) Output Probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification, huggingface-transformers

Say I’ve trained a BERT model for classification. I’d like to calculate the proportional impact each input token is having on the predicted output.

For example - and this is very general - if I have a model that labels input text as `{‘about dogs’ : 0, ‘about cats’ : 1}`, the following input sentence:
`s = 'this is a sentence about a cat'`
should output very close to:
`1`

HOWEVER, what I’d like is to calculate each input’s impact on that final prediction, e.g. (assuming we’re tokenizing on the level of words - which is not how it would be done in practice, I know):
`{this : .01, is: .005, a : .02, sentence : .0003, about : [some other low prob], a: [another low prob], cat : 0.999999}`

Intuitively I’d think this means running a forward pass with the input sentence, then looking at the backprop values? But I’m not quite sure how you’d do that. Thoughts?

**NOTE**
Assume everything is implemented in PyTorch. My current use case is with HuggingFace, but I'd want to generalize this anyway.

Comment: Are you using the `CLS` token to classify your text?

Comment: Yes, I am. Though what I'm interested is the impact of individual tokens on the output probabilities.

Comment: I think you could do this when you use the attention output and check the attention each token pays to the CLS token.